# headless_shell sgementation fault when start running on arm64

Tags: arm64, google-chrome-headless, ninja, gn

when i finished cross-compile chrome for amr64, I found that an error 'Segmentation fault' would be reported after starting chrome.

The cross-compile server system version is: `Linux version 4.4.0-157-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-037) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) )`

The arm64 server system version is: `Linux centos7.6-aarch-template 4.14.0-115.e17a.0.1.aarch64`

Here are params in `args.gn`:

```
import("//build/args/headless.gn")
target_os = "linux"
symbol_level = 0
is_debug = false
blink_symbol_level = 0
target_cpu = "arm64"
disable_histogram_support = true
```

The `autoninja -C out/Debug headless_shell` is used for compling headless chrome.

Then copy the Debug folder to the ARM server

But when I run `./headless_shell` on the server, there is only segmentation fault, no more information.
just like this:

```
./headless_shell
Segmentation fault.
```

Any help or guidance on how I can solve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I experience the same. Tested both Alpine and Ubuntu, and still no progress, it's always "Segmentation fault". Looks like, there's no Chromium build ready for ARM yet.